# Can I not fast certain days of Ramadan month but make up for it after it ends?

Tags: sawm

Can I not fast certain days of Ramadan month but make up for it after Ramadan ends?
It's because of school and stuff.

Comment: Nope, you have to fast.

Answer (score 0):

Assalm o Alaikum...
Ramadan fasts are obligated like Prayers...
As you can not skip or delay prayers without a genuine reason... Similarly delaying fasts of Ramadan without a genuine reason is not allowed...
So please try to make your fasts in this holy month...
Although it is a little bit difficult but the reward after it is much greater..
Jzk